# HTML date input giving wrong date in PHP POST

Tags: php, html

My code looks like this:

```
<form action="uitdraai.php" method="post">
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="fiets">

<?php
require 'db_con.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_fietsen";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0) {
    foreach($query_run as $student) {
?>
        <option value="<?= $student['fiets'] ?>"><?= $student['fiets'] ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>

    </select>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="startdatum"><h8>Startdatum</h8></label>
        <input type="date" name="startdatum">
    </div>

    <label for="einddatum">Einddatum</label>
    <input type="date" name="einddatum">
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download pdf" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        <!-- <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a> -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Then for the php part (uitdraai.php):

```
$startdatum = strtotime($_POST['startdatum']);
if ($startdatum) {
  $startdatum = date('Y-m-d');
} 

$einddatum = strtotime($_POST['einddatum']);
if ($einddatum) {
  $einddatum = date('Y-m-d');
}
```

Seems clear to me, however when i echo the two dates I get:

```
2023-03-01 2023-03-01
```

Both todays date. Is there something wrong with my form?

When I try to get the raw input from html it seems to be random numbers.

Comment: You're overwriting the value every time. `if $startdatum contains a value, assign the current date to it`. You probably want `if(!$startdatum)` and `if(!$einddatum)`

Comment: or maybe `$startdatum = !empty($_POST['startdatum']) ? strtotime($_POST['startdatum']) : date('Y-m-d');` but this assumes your POST value has convertable date string.

Answer (score 2):

```
$startdatum = strtotime($_POST['startdatum']);
if ($startdatum) {
  $startdatum = date('Y-m-d', $startdatum );
} 

$einddatum = strtotime($_POST['einddatum']);
if ($einddatum) {
  $einddatum = date('Y-m-d', $einddatum );
}
```

I hope this solve your problem.

you're reassigning current date to variables instead of converting format.